# Redirect GET request and include an authentication token

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

GAE = Google App Engine
GCS = Google Cloud Storage

My GAE application receives GET requests for files that are actually stored on a bucket of GCS. I would like to redirect those requests to their real location and include an auth token in the redirected request so that GCS accepts to serve them.

To issue a redirection, GAE exposes `webapp2.RequestHandler.redirect` which does not let me add any header to the original request.

Is it possible to redirect the GET request and include an auth token in it?

Comment: Which part are you finding difficult? I don't know GCS, so quite possibly I can't help you, but just reading the question I can't tell whether you're stuck because GCS requires the auth token to be in some place that's difficult for you to reach (a cookie on a separate domain, perhaps), or you're stuck because you don't know how to serve a 302 response on GAE.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I’ve tried to clarify my problem. Does it make it any clearer?

Comment: I think so. So GCS requires the auth token to be in some place that's difficult to reach (the request headers sent by the browser).

Answer (score 2):

HTTP redirect is just a response with 3XX status code. You can't forward a header or response body to a new location.

That said, you will want to implement some logic on a client. Your client has to issue one request to your GAE application, then process the response, and then issue one more request to  GCS with all the headers or body that you want to supply (auth token in your case).

Answer (score 1):

I updated another thread with this as well, but just in case you didn't see it.

In the upcoming 1.6.4 release of AppEngine we've added the ability to pass a Google Storage object name to the blobstore.send_blob() to send Google Storage files of any size from you AppEngine application. We create the correct token for your application to access the objects in the Google Storage bucket.

[Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/forum/?place=topic%2Fgoogle-appengine%2FJKC07lp8q5g%2Fdiscussion) is the pre-release announcement for 1.6.4.